# Android send custom email STARTTLS port 587

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I need to send an email using client settings. Access to the host uses STARTTLS security using port 587.
To test rode the following code (changed customer data for security):

```
String host = "zimbra.mydomain.net.br";
        String port = "587";
        String address = "mail@mydomain.net.br";
        String pass = "******";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", address); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(address));

        Multipart multiPart=new MimeMultipart();

        InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress("rnn2@live.com"); 
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);

        message.setSubject("Send Auto-Mail"); 
        message.setContent(multiPart); 
        message.setText("Demo For Sending Mail in Android Automatically");

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, address, pass);

        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
```

Exception:

> javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
>     nested exception is:
>       com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.7.1 unknown[000.000.000.00]: Client host rejected: Access denied

-- EDIT --

> DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1]
>   DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
>   DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "zimbra.myclientaddress.net.br", port 587, isSSL false
>   220 zimbra.myclientaddress.net.br ESMTP Postfix
>   DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "zimbra.myclientaddress.net.br", port: 587
>   EHLO localhost
>   250-zimbra.myclientaddress.net.br
>   250-PIPELINING
>   250-SIZE 1741203456
>   250-VRFY
>   250-ETRN
>   250-STARTTLS
>   250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>   250-8BITMIME
>   250 DSN
>   DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
>   DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "1741203456"
>   DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "VRFY", arg ""
>   DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ETRN", arg ""
>   DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
>   DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
>   DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
>   DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
>   DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
>   MAIL FROM:
>   250 2.1.0 Ok
>   RCPT TO:
>   554 5.7.1 : Client host rejected: Access denied
>   DEBUG SMTP: Invalid Addresses
>   DEBUG SMTP:   rnn2@live.com
>   DEBUG SMTP: Sending failed because of invalid destination addresses
>   RSET
>   250 2.0.0 Ok

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the server is rejecting your request, perhaps based on your IP address, or perhaps based on the sender or recipient addresses.  Add [session.setDebug(true)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and check the debug output for more clues as to why it's failing.

Also, you probably want to [change Session.getDefaultInstance to Session.getInstance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: I activated the session.setDebug (true) and enter the information collected in the description of my question. Please check, is that the server is rejecting the same IP address as the email address is a valid address.

Comment: You're using a very old version of JavaMail.  Because of that, you're not authenticating to your mail server.  Upgrade to the [latest version](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) and I think it will fix your problem.  If that's not possible, set "mail.smtp.auth" to "true" and see if that helps.

Comment: I updated to the latest version of JavaMail and auditioned unsuccessfully, then insert the property "mail.smtp.auth" to true and also it still fails, the same exception is also thrown.

Comment: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[191.249.39.175]>: Client host rejected: Access denied

Comment: I added this e-mail account in native android client emails and it worked, then the mail server is ok, the problem really is in my code.